# Replacing multiple values in a string - Python

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a string say `'I have a string'` and a list `['I', 'string']`. if i have to remove all the elements in the list from the given string, a proper for loop is working fine. But when I try the same with a list comprehension, it is not working as expected but returns a list.

```
my_string = 'I have a string'
replace_list = ['I', 'string']
for ele in replace_list:
    my_string = my_string.replace(ele, '')
# results --> ' have a '
[my_string.replace(ele, '') for ele in replace_list]
# results --> [' have a string', 'I have a ']
```

Is there any way to do it more efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regex:

```
import re

to_replace = ['I', 'string']
regex = re.compile('|'.join(to_replace))

re.sub(regex, '', my_string)
```

Output:

```
' have a '
```

Alternatively, you can use `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

def bound_replace(string, old):
    return string.replace(old, '')

reduce(bound_replace, to_replace, my_string)
```

Output:

```
' have a '
```

Comment: alternatively you can use a lambda to replace your function `reduce(lambda string,old: string.replace(old, ''),to_replace,my_string)`

Comment: @AJS I prefer to avoid lambda functions where possible, because I find Python's syntax in that regard quite clunky.

Comment: yea its a matter of preference.

Comment: So there is no any function like `str_replace_all()` in R?

Comment: @SmashGuy I don't know R, but there is no inbuilt function to replace multiple arbitrary substrings. There's `translate` for single characters.